# Python mysql.connector multithreading issues

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am getting errors while using an object with a mysql connection in a multithreaded context. The error I get is `MySQL Connection not available` and I am almost sure is because of the multithread, but I don't know what would be the best way to overcome this.

I've made an example code that creates ten threads and calls an object:

```
threads = []

with MysqlExample({ "host" : "XXXX", 
                              "database" : "XXXX",
                              "user" : "XXXX", 
                              "password" : "XXXX" }) as my_example:
    for _ in range(10): 
        th = threading.Thread( target = my_example.example3,
                                   args = (), )
        th.start()
        threads.append( th ) 
        
    for th in threads : 
        th.join()
```

The called object can be used with "with", also and is the following:

```
class MysqlExample(object):

    def __init__(self, config : dict ):
        self._conn = mysql.Connect( **config )
        self._conn.autocommit = True
    
    def close(self):
        self._example2()
        self._conn.close()
    
    def __enter__(self):
        self._example1()
        return self
        
    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb ):
        self.close()
    
    def _example1(self):
        cur = self._conn.cursor()
        cur.execute( '''select * from simple_test''' )
        cur.fetchall()
        
    def _example2(self):
        cur = self._conn.cursor()
        cur.execute('''select * from simple_test''' )
        cur.fetchall()
        
    def example3(self):
        cur = self._conn.cursor()
        cur.execute('''select * from simple_test''' )
        cur.fetchall()
```

Apparently, the connection is lost when the second thread starts. Using a connection pool would overcome this problem??? I've tried using a `Lock()` object in every method (`example1`, `example2`, `example3`) but that doesn't solve the problem.

## Update: connection pooling doesn't solve the issue

Upon request of a commenter here, I've tried to make an example using
connection pooling. Here the error is `ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists`. Below is my code. Any idea how to overcome this error???

```
class MysqlExamplePooling(object):

    def __init__(self, config : dict ):
        self._pool = MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name = "MysqlExamplePooling",
                                                      pool_size = 3,
                                                      **config)
    
    def _conn(self): 
        cnx = self._pool.get_connection()
        cnx.autocommit = True
        return cnx
    
    def close(self):
        self._example2()
        self._pool.close()
    
    def __enter__(self):
        self._example1()
        return self
        
    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb ):
        self.close()
    
    def _example1(self):
        cur = self._conn().cursor()
        cur.execute( '''select * from simple_test''' )
        cur.fetchall()
        
    def _example2(self):
        cur = self._conn().cursor()
        cur.execute('''select * from simple_test''' )
        cur.fetchall()
        
    def example3(self):
        cur = self._conn().cursor()
        cur.execute('''select * from simple_test''' )
        cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: Ofc, Connection pooling is the way to go.

Comment: I will try to create an example with connection pooling, to see where it goes

Comment: @Kris: I'am afraid that not: weakly referenced object....

Answer (score 0):

Either surround every call with a lock, or use connection pooling but ensure that you don't exhaust the pool.
It comes out that the `mysql.connector` library is a little pickly about what can be done with multithreading. The options are limited:

### Surround every use of a `mysql` connection with a lock:

```
import threading
import mysql.connector as mysql

class MysqlExample(object):

def __init__(self, config : dict ):
    [....]
    self._lock = threading.Lock()

def _example1(self):
    with self._lock:
        cur = self._conn.cursor()
        cur.execute( '''select * from simple_test''' )
        cur.fetchall()
```

### Use connection pooling but the limit of connections is 32

And you cannot know in advance how many are left. And, you must make
sure that you don't leave weak references.

**Bad:**

```
def example3(self):
    cur = self._conn().cursor()
    cur.execute('''select * from simple_test''' )
    cur.fetchall()
```

**Good:**

```
def example3(self):
    conn = self._conn()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('''select * from simple_test''' )
    cur.fetchall()
```

See the difference, dear me? I've created a local variable called `conn`
to keep the value of the connection. Thus, the connection object is kept
alive until the end of the method and no weak reference error is obtained.

Comment: Use `with _lock` – your current code won't release the lock correctly.

Comment: ok, changed the example